# How to place two divs side by side when stretched to full size?

Tags: html, css

I have two `div`s streched to the size of the parent(`body`), but on application of inline-block attribute the divs are placed one below the other instead of beside each other.

I want them to be placed beside each other, such that i need to scroll horizontally instead of vertically.

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wJ73v/364/

```
html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="red-blue"></div>

css

html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.red-blue {
     background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
     height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Of course they do, they are set to be 100% wide. What is it you want to happen?

Comment: I want them to be placed beside each other, such that i need to scroll horizontally instead of vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this, add `white-space: nowrap` to the `body`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.red-blue {
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="red-blue"></div>
```

If you want to get rid of that vertical scroll, you can set `overflow-y: hidden;` on the `body`.

If you need the scroll, you can use `flexbox`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
.red-blue {
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="red-blue"></div>
```

Comment: Yes thanks this works, but what exactly does nowrap do ?

Comment: @RakeshRenzous In this case it tells inline/inline-block to stay on 1 line